# How to permanently exclude web site's App_Data folder contents from TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm finding that I need an App_Code folder in my web site, and I also need to permanently exclude it from TFS. I'm using VS2012 and TFS2012.

I've discovered some offered solutions, but they generally lead back to clicking on the "Detected Changes" link in the Team Explorer pane in order to open the "Promote Candidate Changes" window.

I can find "Included Changes". I can find "Excluded Changes". Neither contains the link to "Promote Candidate Changes".

I can't find anything marked "Detected Changes", link or otherwise. I haven't found anything that looks like a "Promote Candidate Changes" window.

Any clues as to why or to an entirely different solution that has nothing to do with those options would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Server or Local workspaces?

Comment: Local, unless I misunderstand the usage of the term "workspace" in this context. We maintain copies of the files on local drives for development, and they go to a server on check-in.

Comment: In Visual Studio Source Control Explorer, goto the Workspaces section at the top and pick "Workspaces..." from the combo box. Then edit the one you have and then click advanced, it will tell you there what type you have. Local = SVN Style, Server = VSS Style.

Comment: It says Location = Server. (I'd just about given up on finding it when I saw the two little inobtrusive dots on the Source Control menu bar that listed Workspace when I clicked it.)

Comment: Server Workspaces store all their information on the Server. So you will not see the Included or Exluded Changes prompts. If you swap to a Local Workspace it will appear.

Comment: Just as an side, apparently the designer of that menu assumed I'd have the Source Control explorer open as a main window and thus see the whole thing stretched out across the top. For me it works so much better having the source control as a tabbed sidebar with the solution explorer.